# Error while running a WordPress and MySQL docker containers using Docker-Compose on an AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I am new to docker compose and I have created the following docker compose file. But when I try to open the WordPress site it shows the following error:

[image]

I am working on an AWS EC2 instance with Ubuntu OS. I tried connecting to the website using:
`http://<IP - ADDRESS>:8090`

The docker-compose.yaml file:
`

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    ports:
      - "8090:80"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: root
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: "password"
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
    networks:
      net:
        ipv4_address: "172.31.32.20"
  mysql:
    image: "mysql:5.7"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "password"
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      net:
        ipv4_address: "172.31.32.21"
networks:
    net:
      ipam:
        driver: default
        config:
          - subnet: "172.31.32.0/20"
```

`

Comment: Maybe a dumb question but have you set your Security Groups for the EC2 instance? If so, what do they look like?

Comment: I have had problems with connectivity when I tried defining rules before so just for experimentation I decided to allow all traffic. So for inbound and outbound rules there are 2 each. One is from all IPv4 and the second is from all IPv6

Comment: The error indicates that your wordpress cannot connect to your database. What is the URL it tries to connect with? Also, do you use the built-in DNS to connect (aka "mysql") or the IP address of what you expect your container to have? If you use the IP method, make sure it is set in a range that AWS does not use for the machines in the VPC itself.